# TYPO3 Empty line on top of downloaded files from server

Tags: typo3

On page I create File Links content element. I've uploaded some files (ext: dxf,pdf,xls).
All is fine, but when I try to download some files from server (not direct link e.g. uploads/media/example.pdf), they don't open.

e.g. with pdf files I have a message "pdf-file was manipulated since creation".

Then I use tool to compare the original and downloaded files (Meld on Linux). It says that downloaded file has an additional empty line on top. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved after checking all php files in typo3conf/ext/ folder on second breaklines after php closing tag